# What is this white box following windows that I click and drag?

Tags: windows-10

When I drag and drop the window into the the box it snaps it onto the screen into the area that corresponds to where I dragged the window to inside the small box. I'd like to know what it is, and how do i disable it? I'm running Windows 10.

[image: Here:]

Comment: Are you referring to Windows Snap? [How do I turn Snap on or off?](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/how-do-i-turn-snap-on-or-off)

Comment: Are you using any third-party software that may be causing that functionality? As far as I know, Windows 10 doesn't have something that looks like that. It looks like you're using Fences and maybe some other Stardock software has that feature.

Comment: Snap doesn't seem to be the problem, and maybe it could be third party software. I'll disable them all one by one to see if that's the issue.

Comment: Ok i found the issue. A utility called MSI True Colour was causing the problem. I have no clue why.

Answer (score 0):

Open the "MSI True Color" program, select "Show Settings" -> "Tools" -> "Desktop Partition," then uncheck "Desktop Partition on" (it may simply look red when checked, gray when unchecked).